# POST request returns an error in Android 9 (JAVASCRIPT / CORDOVA / PHONEGAP )

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

I've have an issue with AJAX, in my app for Android (JS / CORDOVA). My code is like this:

```
$.post("http://mydomain.com.br/getInfos.php" {
    id: id
}, function(json) {
   if (json == "success") {
     alert("Success!");
   } else {
     alert("Error: " + json);
 }
});
```

The response error is:

```
{“readyState”:0,“responseText”:“”,“status”:0,“statusText”:“error”}
```

My code works fine, in android 8 or below....

What might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plugin `cordova plugin add cleartext` in order to use non secure origins or modify config.xml specifying `android:usesCleartextTraffic` like at this issue [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)